# how to draw a line on unimported image in python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, line, draw

Hi I started to study OpenCV in python and I copied this code from the tutorial :

```
import numpy as np  
import cv2 as cv  
img=np.zeros((512,512,3),np.uint8)  
img=cv.line(img,(0,0),(300,300),(0,0,255),4)  
cv.imshow('draw',img)  
cv.waitKey(0)
```

When I run the code I get this error :

```
error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function imshow
```

I can show the image before drawing the line on it, how to fix this ?

Comment: OK on my machine.

Comment: also works in mine... maybe you can describe more details, like version number or how did you installed opencv in your pc?

Comment: O_o so is there any way to fix this ?

Comment: I am working on ubuntu I don't remember where I copied the code to download OpenCV, so how to check the version for an update?

Comment: [`cv2.line`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#line) returns `None`... at least in 2.4.x

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dc/da5/tutorial_py_drawing_functions.html

Comment: @BasharHeeb Are you using OpenCV 3.1.0? Looks like this is yet another part of API that subtly changed between 2.4.x and 3.x

Comment: yes, I'm using 3.1.0, what should I do?

Comment: In that case, this code ought to be working without problems -- it does over here with 3.1.0...

Comment: You don't need the `img=` part. You simply call the function and `img` will be drawn on.
In 3.1.0 cv::line's return value is void.

Comment: thanks, @GáborFekete it works perfect, thanks Dan for your help